# SP13 Accordian View (HTML Script)

Tags: 2013, jquery, css

I am working with SP2013.  My objective is to add an accordion View to a Summary Link Web Part.  I added the Summary Link Web Part. Within the Summary Link Web Part, I created groups.  Then I added a Content Editor Web Part.  Within the Content Editor Web Part, I added the code found below to the HTML code.  The CSS code works, however, the jquery script is not working properly.  Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong with the code?  Thanks for your help.

```
  <  <style type="text/css">
.groupheader{
    background-color: #0072C6;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.groupmarker:hover .groupheader{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0597FF;
}

.dfwp-list{
    background-color: #0072C6;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.75em;
}
.dfwp-list .item:hover{
    background-color: #0597FF;
}
.dfwp-list .link-item a{
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: white;
}
</style>


<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){

        /* Slide up all link items and hide them */
        $(".dfwp-list").slideUp("fast");
        /* Binding a click event handler to the links: */
        $('.groupheader').click(function(e){

            /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
            var dropDown = $(this).next(".dfwp-list");

            /* Closing all other drop down sections, except the current one */
            $('.dfwp-list').not(dropDown).slideUp('slow');
            dropDown.slideToggle('slow');

            /* Preventing the default event (which would be to navigate the browser to the link's address) */
            e.preventDefault();
        })
})
</script>  >
```

Sorce code from Stefan Bauers post [Turn summary link web part into an accordion](http://www.n8d.at/blog/turn-summary-link-web-part-into-an-accordion/).

Comment: Can you please add the code origin. The source is copied 1:1 from my blog post. Thanx.
http://www.n8d.at/blog/turn-summary-link-web-part-into-an-accordion/

Comment: It is good practice at any StackExchange site to honor the origin of code and other sources. Please add a link to the source of your code.

Comment: @StefanBauer I've added a reference to your blog post as the OP didn't.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I will be sure to place the code origin next time.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

what's the error you are getting?
I think your refrence to the JScript is missing....could you please add below lines after the `</style>` and before start of `<script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Waqas Sarwar MCSE for your response. I added "<" & ">" to the post.  I will try your suggestion now.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, Waqas Sarwar MCSE.  I did successfully try your suggestion, however, "gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js" easy plugin is not recommended to be used.  So, I will find a work around.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You should download this plugin and use it locally for example from the style library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem till I removed the following reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. Instead using content query webpart i used script webpart. here is the what it looked like. Ensure your code can access the jquery library

```
<script src="/Style Library/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



​​<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Detect if user view or edit the page
    if($("#MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName").val() == "Browse"){
        // Register accordion
        accordion();
    }

})

var accordion = function(){

    /* Slide up all link items and hide them */
    $(".dfwp-list").slideUp("fast");
    /* Binding a click event handler to the links: */
    $('.groupheader').click(function(e){

        /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
        var dropDown = $(this).next(".dfwp-list");

        /* Closing all other drop down sections, except the current one */
        $('.dfwp-list').not(dropDown).slideUp('slow');
        dropDown.slideToggle('slow');

    })
}
</script>
```